# How do I install the linux version of VSCode on an ARM64 Chromebook?

Tags: linux, debian, visual-studio-code, chromebook

Did I get the following error because my Chromebook has an ARM64 chip instead of Intel?

```
Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done Note, selecting 'code:amd64' instead of './code_1.38.1-1568209190_amd64 (1).deb' Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable distribution that some required packages have not yet been created or been moved out of Incoming. The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies: code:amd64 : Depends: libnotify4:amd64 but it is not installable Depends: libnss3:amd64 (>= 2:3.26) but it is not installable Depends: apt:amd64 but it is not installable Depends: libxkbfile1:amd64 but it is not installable Depends: libsecret-1-0:amd64 but it is not installable Depends: libgtk-3-0:amd64 (>= 3.10.0) but it is not installable Depends: libxss1:amd64 but it is not installable E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I got the above message after downloading the .deb file from https://code.visualstudio.com for my Chromebook with linux (Debian) enabled and entering this command in Terminal:

```
sudo apt install ./code_1.38.1-1568209190_amd64\ (1).deb
```

Microsoft provides instructions for "Debian and Ubuntu based distributions" here: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/linux.

Answer (score 4):

> Did I get the following error because my Chromebook has an ARM64 chip instead of Intel?

At this time Visual Studio Code compiled by Microsoft only supports x86 processors.  The error message you received surrounding unmet dependencies with AMD64 indicates this fact.

Due to the fact Visual Studio Code is open source the open source community has ARM support covered.

Source: [Community builds of Visual Studio Code for Chromebooks and Raspberry Pi](https://code.headmelted.com/)

Answer (score 2):

The ARM64 version of Visual Studio Code is now available on the VS website:

https://code.visualstudio.com/Download

(Available for both Debian/Ubuntu and Redhat/Fedora)

Comment: While installing with snap. This error showed. But I wasn't listening: "error: snap "code" is not available on stable for this architecture (arm64) but exists on other" ;  didn't see arm but two times amd...
       architectures (amd64)." thx for help, for me that works

Answer (score 0):

I recently asked the same question on a google forum and a guy helped out, he gave me a Github link and some code that gave a Debian file, I enabled Linux and right-clicked the file, chose download with Linux, and after a small wait and startup, I had VS code on my Chromebook.

Here the Instructions and the link, skip part 1 of you just clicked on the link and downloaded it.

Step 1; curl -L https://aka.ms/linux-arm64-deb > code_arm64.deb

Step 2; sudo apt install ./code_arm64.deb

---

You can also just right click on the file and click install with Linux as I did, no need for a terminal, but you do have to enable Linux.

Comment: Good to know that there is a short link, but Microsoft now offer ARM 64 builds officially on their website: https://code.visualstudio.com/download#

Comment: "I enabled Linux".... what does this men please ?